# 2014 Honda Accord: Low Tire Pressure light still on & oil life still showing 40% after recent tire repair & oil change

Tags: honda, accord, tire-pressure, oil-life-indicator

I just took my 2014 Honda Accord in for a tire repair and oil change on Wednesday, and as of today my low tire pressure light is still on and my Oil Life monitor still shows 40%. It's like they didn't do anything, but they're a trusted mechanic I've used for years, I see where they repaired the tire, and yesterday I checked my pressures and they're all fine. Does the Oil Life monitor actually check the quality of the oil or is it just based on driving distance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oil life indicators try to predict the degradation of the oil using a combination of engine run time, driving distance, number of cold engine starts and similar data.  It does not actually check the quality of the oil.

On the 2014 Accord, the maintenance monitor keeps track of other maintenance as well, but they cannot be reset individually (except at a Honda dealer).  The mechanic may not have reset it because it would reset maintenance items that had not been performed.  The owners manual (which is easily downloadable from Honda) can explain how to see what maintenance is due, and how to reset it on your own.

On this year Accord, I believe the tire pressure system has to be calibrated each time after the tires are re-inflated.  This is easy to do: press and hold the tire pressure monitoring button until the associated light on the dash flashes twice.  The car will then automatically calibrate over the next 20 miles.

Comment: Do they still recommend that you drive a certain distance and/or at a certain speed to get the calibration to work (I forget the details)?

Comment: Note that there is such a thing as an oil quality sensor. While it cannot measure quality itself, it can measure a decline over time. BMW has those for example.

Answer (score 3):

Without your foot on brake, press the power button to turn on accessories. On the instrument cluster push the button several times until oil life is displayed. With oil life displayed hold the button in until it starts blinking. Let off the button and then hold the button in again until it resets. Your mechanic probably just forgot to reset it.

Comment: Yeah, my experience is that it's about 50/50 if the dealer resets the oil light and near zero that any other mechanic does.